# Pandas - Better way to handle date format conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the input date as object type in YYYY/MM/DD format, which I would like to convert at the end to MM/DD/YYYY for reporting use case.

There are multiple transformations on the date filed, so I initially convert from object type to date type using below code. There are additional transformation based on date filed for ex: filtering specific date range...

```
df_source_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_source_data['date'])
```

At the end, I would need the final set of columns from dataframe (which are maintained on a config as list) including date, however I would need date field in MM/DD/YYYY format.

```
final_columns=['date','column1','column2','column3'] # config entry

df_final_data[final_columns] # final select for reporting
```

I can convert the date format using strftime as below, but is there any better way to do this instead of adding a separate line again to convert the filed to desired format (ie first converting from object type to date type, apply filters and at the end convert date to desired format), instead somehow this coming as part of config list or any better way in the code?

```
df_final_data['date']=df_final_data['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any better way to do this instead of adding a separate line again to convert the filed to desired format (ie first converting from object type to date type, apply filters and at the end convert date to desired format)? TLDR no.

```
df_source_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_source_data['date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

This would give you your desired format immediately, however if you are applying datetime transformations in between these will still be string objects in pandas, severely limiting your datetime filtering. For example, let's say you wanted to subset to the month of June, then immediately converting to the desired string output way you would have to do

```
df_source_data[df_source_data['date'].str[0:2] == '06']
```

instead of just being able to do

```
df_source_data[df_source_data['date'].dt.month == 6]
```

I would suggest performing the to_datetime transformation first as you say and then at the very end converting to the format which you desire.

```
df_source_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_source_data['date'])
...
df_final_data['date']=df_final_data['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: Thanks for the details @bbd108